# DOM nodes keep rising in single page app

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, cordova, handlebars.js

I'm developing a single page app using backbone, handlebars and jquery-mobile. I'm facing a problem that causes DOM nodes to keep rising, no matter how I try to clean them up.

To better demonstrate the issue, I created a simple program that is structured exactly like my app is, and have the same problem. The whole app has only 4 files:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script id="home-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{> header}}            
            <div data-role="content">       
                <a id="page1Link" href="#page1" data-role="button">goto Page1</a>
            </div>  
        {{> footer}}
        </script>
        <script id="page1-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{> header}}
            <div data-role="content">       
                <h1>Hello, am I leaking?</h1>   
            </div>      
        {{> footer}}
        </script>       
        <script id="header-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div id="header" data-id="myHeader" data-role="header" data-position="fixed"              data-theme="a">
                <a href="#home" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>                                 
                <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>                                                  
            </div>
        </script>       
        <script id="footer-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div id="footer" data-id="myFooter" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"  data-theme="a">           
                <h4>Copyright Stuff</h4>                                          
            </div>  
        </script>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="lib/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/backbone.touch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/handlebars.js"></script>       

        <script src="templates/homeView.js"></script>
        <script src="templates/page1View.js"></script>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>  

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"/>     
    </head> 
    <body></body>
</html>
```

main.js :

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "home":"home",
        "page1" : "page1",
    },

    home:function () {
        this.changePage(new HomeView());
    },

    page1:function () {
        this.changePage(new Page1View());       
    },   

    changePage:function (page, argumentos) {
        if (this.currentPage)
            this.currentPage.close();
        this.currentPage = page;
        $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'page');
        var render = page.render();

        $('body').append($(page.el));
        var transition = 'slide';      
        var reverse = false;
        if(argumentos && argumentos[0] == 'true'){
            reverse = true;
        }
        $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {transition: transition, reverse: reverse});                 
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () { 
    Handlebars.registerPartial("header", $("#header-partial").html());
    Handlebars.registerPartial("footer", $("#footer-partial").html());
    var app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
    Backbone.history.navigate('home', {trigger: true});
    Backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {            
        this.unbind();
        this.remove();
    }      
});
```

homeView.js

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: Handlebars.compile($("#home-tpl").html()),

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template({pageTitle:"home"}));         
        return this;
    },

    events : {
        "tap #page1Link" : "gotoPage1",
    },

    gotoPage1 : function() {  
        Backbone.history.navigate('page1', {trigger: true});
    }
});
```

page1View.js

```
var Page1View = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: Handlebars.compile($("#page1-tpl").html()),

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template({pageTitle: "page1"}));
        return this;
    },

    events : {
        "click div#header a" : "back",
    },

    back : function() {
        Backbone.history.navigate('home', {trigger: true});
    },
});
```

If I keep changing between the two views, the DOM node count exhibits the following behavior (The parts of the graphic where memory goes down are the parts I clicked to force garbage collection):

[image: DOM node count increasing]

I'm a beginner in those technologies so I guess I'm doing something wrong. I've searched for an answer to this, but all I could find I've already done (calling remove() and unbind() for every view being destroyed).

So, how can I dispose those nodes?

Comment: I've never used Backbone.js or Handlebars.js but I see that you are using this.remove() in your close() function. The question is, what is the 'this' object when that function is called. If it is a jQuery DOM object then this.remove() should remove it from the DOM. I would stop my debugger at that statement and check what 'this' is when close() is called. Also, check the 'Elements' tab in Chrome Dev Tools to confirm that the expected DOM element is being removed after this.remove() is called.

Comment: I've checked the Elements tab and the DOM is being removed. I don't know how to use a debugger in javascript yet, but if a print "this" it shows: `s {cid: "view7", $el: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], el: div.ui-page.ui-page-theme-a.ui-page-header-fixed.ui-page-footer-fixed.ui-page-ac‌​tive, constructor: function, template: function…}`.

Comment: You don't need to create a new view each time you process a route. Create the view once, then update when needed. If you need to change from one "page" to another, simply empty the html of the el and render something else into it. Also, I wouldn't redefine the remove method that has already been defined for you as Backbone Views are already doing some cleanup (unbinding events and removing the el from the DOM) for you.

Comment: I can try to just create the views once, but I think the cleanup code is correct, like explained [here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not removed the referenced on $.mobile.changePage.

```
  $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {transition: transition, reverse: reverse});
```

However, I am not familiar with jquery-mobile. But I have some comments on the backbonejs code.

My suggestion is adding a DIV element on index.html which acting as the view-port for your app. Then, all your view object can be bind on this DIV.

index.html

```
<div id="myviewport"></div>
```

HomeView.js

```
var HomeView = {
....
initialize: function () {
    this.$el = $("#myviewport");
},
....
};
```

also you can do something like on rendering

```
//main.js
//since page.render() return this, you can chain them up
//In other 
$("body").append(page.render().$el);
```

Comment: I don't understand how `$.mobile.changePag` is leaking memory. I'm using the same way the examples in their homepage do.

Comment: Just a guess. Since you have been called this.close() and this.unbind() to cancel references about your dom nodes on Backbone View and jquery, the remaining reference is the one you pass in to the $.mobile.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {
                    this.undelegateEvents();
                    Backbone.Validation.unbind(this);
                    this.$el.removeData().unbind().empty();
                    if (this.model) { 
                        this.model.off();
                        this.model.destroy({ silent: true }); 
                    }
};
```

undelegateEvents is a main Method of backbone to undelegete all events
Backbone.Validation.unbind(this); Unbind backbone validation